# The subjunctive mood can be used freely for any hypothetical situation or is limited to some verbs and phrases?

Tags: present-subjunctive

Is it correct to use the subjunctive mood like this: "The description would be the one the user *assign*".

I ask because it is said that the subjunctive mood is mostly used with certain phrases or verbs.  For example it is used with "wish" but not with "hope" (reference: [English club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm)).

So I would like to know if for example the sentence "The description would be the one the user *assign*" would sound weird or if it would be quickly understood without doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't say "The description would be the one the user assign".

This is ungrammatical in modern English.

It is better to err on the side of the indicative (the non-subjunctive form) if unsure. The subjunctive is used rather less than its equivalent in some other languages.

In your phrase, you could use "assigned", but "assigns" would also work.